# Change old PC hard drive but keep Windows XP

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp

I have an old, very old, HP laptop which runs Windows XP. It came installed with the PC (means that it is an OEM build, if I got it right). I'd like to replace its HDD for a better one, but I want to keep Windows XP. Yes, I am totally aware of the security issues.

I've read that one can download the Windows image from the Microsoft website, but that's only for Windows 7 beyond, since there are no images of Windows XP there. How can I proceed?

Edit: I do not have any Windows installation CD.

Comment: Use software to Clone the old hard drive to the new one.....https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree

Comment: You aren’t clear if you want to just upgrade the hard drive and keep the old software, OS and data intact. Or, if you want to change the hard drive and reinstall Windows XP from scratch.

Comment: @Appleoddity Keeping everything intact would be the ideal option.

Comment: Then cloning, as suggested, is the answer.

Comment: You can easily find Windows XP ISOs online, which should work if you have your product key (which can be recovered using a keyfinder script): https://softlay.net/operating-system/windows-xp-sp3-iso-full-version-free-download.html